# Automatically switch language in Gnus, depending on recipient

Tags: emacs, message, gnus

When using my custom version of th-message-switch-ispell-dictionary (see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnus-english/2007-08/msg00062.html):

```
(defun my-message-switch-ispell-dictionary ()
  (save-excursion
    (message-narrow-to-headers-or-head)
    (let ((newsgroups (message-fetch-field "Newsgroups"))
          (to         (message-fetch-field "To")))
      (message "Newsgroup or To = %s." (or newsgroups to))
      (if newsgroups
          (cond ((string-match (rx bol "fr.") newsgroups)
                 (ispell-change-dictionary "francais"))
                (t
                 (ispell-change-dictionary "american")))
        ;; email
        (ispell-change-dictionary "francais")))))

(add-hook 'message-setup-hook 'my-message-switch-ispell-dictionary)
```

I experience the error:

```
message-position-on-field: Search failed: "^--text follows this line--$"
```

when creating a mail or a post (and no "--text follows this line--" is present anymore)...

Any idea about what goes wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the `--text follows this line--` is not getting inserted. As alternative try modifying the function above as follows

```lisp
(require 'sendmail)
(defun my-message-switch-ispell-dictionary ()
  (save-excursion
    (narrow-to-region (point-min) (mail-header-end))            ;; changed this line
    (let ((newsgroups (message-fetch-field "Newsgroups"))
          (to         (message-fetch-field "To")))
      (message "Newsgroup or To = %s." (or newsgroups to))
      (if newsgroups
          (cond ((string-match (rx bol "fr.") newsgroups)
                 (ispell-change-dictionary "francais"))
                (t
                 (ispell-change-dictionary "american")))
        ;; email
        (ispell-change-dictionary "francais")))))

(add-hook 'message-setup-hook 'my-message-switch-ispell-dictionary)
```

The line added does the same thing `(message-narrow-to-headers-or-head)` but does not rely on the ("--text follows this line--") `mail-header-separator` being inserted.

Comment: It did not help. Though, the above does well work if I comment the following line of gnus-alias:

Comment: ;; (add-hook 'message-setup-hook 'gnus-alias-determine-identity)

Comment: I tried searching for `gnus-alias-determine-identity`, it is NOT included in vanilla emacs perhaps you will have to install it separately I found a copy at (https://github.com/emacsmirror/gnus-alias). BTW if commenting the line works (and you do not need it) consider removing it altogether.

Comment: I do need it... as I have different "personalities" (for work, for friends, etc.) and you can change it on the fly, unlike gnus-posting-style... Thanks for helping!